# Should We Still Be Using the RallyOn11 Tag, Even Though the Conference Was Last Month?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, promotion, tags

I noticed that some questions were still being tagged as [rallyon11](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rallyon11). Should we still be using this tag, as the conference was 3 weeks ago.

In addition, how does this tag, (and [definition-of-done](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition-of-done)) help the site? Since these are meta-tags, [which are generally discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), should there be a point where we stop using them and possibly remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think neither [rallyon11](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rallyon11) or [definition-of-done](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition-of-done) really helps. Well, the latter actually does make sense but only as long as it is connected with definition of done, e.g. [this question is a good example](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/2533/how-do-you-define-done-on-a-project-or-task). Otherwise people will who join the site in a couple of weeks or later will get confused when it comes to the tag meaning.

Besides, if the question belongs to the site it should have at least a couple of non-meta tags, shouldn't it?

I'd vote for removing [rallyon11](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rallyon11) and proper usage of [definition-of-done](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition-of-done).

Comment: agree, I removed [rallyon11], it has served its purpose and is too localized now

Comment: +1 on proper usage of definition of done. What do other people think about RallyOn11 tag?  Even though the conference was a month ago, I believe there is still value to it to help give context to questions and askers that came out of the conference, as well as transparency.

Comment: I know Jeff and the SE Team don't support Meta tags, but considering that our PMSE community is now made up of other communities, such as RallyOn and the Definition of Done conference, I can definitely see the argument that these individuals may find value in searching for material and questions that arose from the conference. I say we keep them for now as an experiment and if we start to see problems arise from this, then we can act quickly to remove them. The main thing to look out for is discussion questions, "not a real question" questions, and those that would go better on forums.

Comment: Nevermind. It looks like Jeff already deleted them. I think a good keyword for anyone to use from RallyOn who is looking for material would be "Agile", as I've noticed most of the questions are related to that subject. Perhaps that *is* better than using a meta tag...